# How do I decrypt a file using node-rsa with public and private keys?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, encryption, node-rsa

I was following this tutorial on [medium](https://medium.com/@ian.mundy/writing-a-node-js-script-4baef96104da).  However the tutorial does not explain how to decrypt the encrypted file.  Nor does it explain how the public / private keys are used.

Simply running decrypt does not work with the error below.

[image]

Relevant documentation appears to be on [npmjs.com](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-rsa#encryptingdecrypting).

**Actual Code**

```
// node modules
const fs = require('fs');

// npm modules
const parseArgs = require('minimist');
const NodeRSA = require('node-rsa');

// get command line arguments
const argv = parseArgs(process.argv.slice(2));
// console.dir(argv);

// read a file
const file = fs.readFileSync('' + argv.file, 'utf8');

// generate keys
const key = new NodeRSA().generateKeyPair();
const publicKey = key.exportKey('pkcs8-public-pem');
const privateKey = key.exportKey('pkcs1-pem');

// write public key
fs.openSync('keys/public.pem', 'w');
fs.writeFileSync('keys/public.pem', publicKey, 'utf8');

// write private key
fs.openSync('keys/private.pem', 'w');
fs.writeFileSync('keys/private.pem', privateKey, 'utf8');

// write encrypted file
const encrypted = key.encrypt(file, 'base64');
fs.openSync('encrypted.txt', 'w');
fs.writeFileSync('encrypted.txt', encrypted, 'utf8');

// read encrypted file
const fileEncrypted = fs.readFileSync('encrypted.txt', 'utf8');
const decrypted = key.decrypt(fileEncrypted, 'base64'); // error here
// has to do with key generation?
```

**default.txt**

test

**encrypted.txt**

> qLs0dUez+LzhlNBGnvEzLRdYF0HUHoRignMxT2MZO7Qs8tMvkmWbiA1oxJbT7ZC5bPS+dHvFgbiWbdje/3/Y17JT8JxflryJU6394UPfsTDLmtZZroemTtTzJxVnGZlw0IyQtfn79eysQaEoKMQ9hKjDySxO1gLwJJZ1DoxW7CNu0BqfcGUMcREQ+ozrhKpMRK0piWUWqHYwX0EIxQT8/rh5ER+tCdh4lR7N5+FPA4VOde3z/36DvQ9KOMChS7m91aH0QXUqhMaHtjslvcoj4i1Rwzd0qn1imHPc8LncZz6hv2deRqU65rS+M6UeC9LWJjblVf2er25x8B1yszaV+A==

Comment: It is just a text file that says "test".  So pretty small.

Comment: Shouldn't you be encrypting the data with public key and decrypting the data with private key? Right now you are using the key pair to do that. I don't know the Node js api but in most languages you do like `publicKey.encrypt()` and then decrypt using the private key.

Comment: Please check the tutorial I posted by Medium and you will see the Google Engineer, author does it this way.  I posted a comment as well asking why he did not use the pair in his example.

Comment: No you do not need to specifically use the public key to perform encryption, that's implied. Encryption using the private key is called a signature.

Comment: Not sure why he created a public and private key pair with out using them.  Seems like half a tutorial.  Where is part 2?

Answer (score 1):

You are not decrypting the data correctly, the `encoding` argument of `NodeRSA.prototype.decrypt(buffer, encoding)` is the desired result encoding, not the input encoding.

Although the decrypt method is said to take a buffer via the JSDoc:

```
/**
 * Decrypting data method with private key
 *
 * @param buffer {Buffer} - buffer for decrypting
 * @param encoding - encoding for result string, can also take 'json' or 'buffer' for the automatic conversion of this type
 * @returns {Buffer|object|string}
 */
```

You can trace the code to see that if `buffer` is a string it is assumed to be in `base64` encoding:

```
buffer = _.isString(buffer) ? Buffer.from(buffer, 'base64') : buffer;
```

We can simplify your problem down by ignoring the file system interactions to see how a round trip works:

```
const key = new NodeRSA().generateKeyPair();

// Encrypt the utf8 encoded input string and output a base64 encoded string
const encrypted = key.encrypt('test', 'base64');
console.log(encrypted);

// Decrypt the base64 encoded input string and output a utf8 encoded string
const decrypted = key.decrypt(encrypted, 'utf8');
console.log(decrypted);
```

Alternatively you could explicitly convert the input and output to and from buffers respectively, this may help you understand what is happening under the hood:

```
const key = new NodeRSA().generateKeyPair();

const input = Buffer.from('test', 'utf8');

const encrypted = key.encrypt(input);
console.log(encrypted.toString('base64'));

const decrypted = key.decrypt(encrypted);
console.log(decrypted.toString('utf8'));
```

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to decrypt the **clear text file** .. 
Try decrypt on the encrypted file.